# Grouping error with PREVGROUPVAL function

Tags: reporting

I am trying to create a month-over-month quantity difference report, but when I enter something like the following:

```
PREVGROUPVAL(Quantity__c:SUM, Report_Date__c)
```

I get the following error:

```
You must select a grouping context to use any report summary function
```

I've tried various iterations of summary fields and grouping fields and can't get it to work using any data.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing this in lightning, I suggest editing the report in Classic.  For the PREVGROUPVAL function you need to choose a grouping level, which it seems like you can't do in Lightning.

Comment: That was it, thanks.  I've spent so much time trying to get everybody out of Classic I forget that sometimes you have to go back.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can select the grouping in lightening version. Go to 'Display' tab first and choose the specific grouping. After, proceed with the prevgroupval formula.[image]

Comment: I tried to do this in Lightning using your answer, but I could not get it to work. Then I switched to Classic and got it working pretty quickly. Went back to Lightning to see what the result looked like overthere. And there the formula and settings are exactly as I had tried them the first time in Lightning, only then it was rejected (same problem as OP). Strange...